# JavaScript: Convert array of strings to array of variables and pass it as arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, for example:

```js
argumentsArray = ["arg1", "arg2"];
```

And I have a function:

```js
function1 = function () {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
};
```

Now of course executing `function1` will throw an error because `arg1` and `arg2` aren't defined. But I don't want to define these, I want them used as arguments, like so:

```js
function1 = function (arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
};
```

Now we could execute `function1` when we pass two arguments to it:

```js
function1("string1", "string2");
// will log "string1" and "string2"
```

But the problem is, I can't change the source code of `function1`. I can't edit it's arguments. I'm aware of the `bind()` and `apply()` function, but they would do the wrong thing, because the actually apply the strings:

```js
getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray = function () {
    return function () {
        return function1.apply(this, argumentsArray);
    };
};

getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray();
// would return function1("arg1", "arg2");
```

The thing is, `arg1` and `arg2` are not defined yet. They aren't strings or any other thing yet. My code looks something like this:

```js
function1 = function () {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
};

argumentsArray = ["arg1", "arg2"];

defineArgs = function() {
    arg1 = "hey";
    arg2 = "hello";
};

getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray = function (argumentsArray) {
    argumentsToUse = convertArrayOfStringsToArrayOfVariables(argumentsArray);
    // HOW???

    return function () {
        return function1(argumentsToUse[0], argumentsToUse[1]);
    };
    // or what should i put here???
};

getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray();
// should return this:
// function1 = function(arg1, arg2) {
//     console.log(arg1);
//     console.log(arg2);
// };
// without executing it.
```

So what I'm really looking for is a function that turns an array of strings into an array of variables with the names of these strings:

```js
["arg1", "arg2"] --> [arg1, arg2]
```

But making this directly would be a problem, because JavaScript then searches for these variables. As I said, these variables aren't defined...

---

One I idea I had is to use `apply()` and pass an Array `with eval("string")`s like so:

```js
getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray = function () {
        return function () {
            return function1.apply(
                this,
                [eval(argumentsArray[0]), eval(argumentsArray[1])]
            );
        };
    };

getFunction1WithArgumentsFromArray();
// would return "arg1 is not defined", because eval() executes the function as I define it
```

---

This may seem very very unnecessary to you, but as I already said, I can't change the `function1` so I have to create it's arguments list in another function. I mean, of course I **can** change it, but the project I'm working on, uses an array to get arguments.

Comment: If `function1` is trying to work with variables which flat-out aren't defined, it's arguably wrong. How'd you get into this particular predicament…?

Comment: You can access the arguemtns passed to function1 w/ arguments object like this --> arguments[index]. So defining arg1 and arg2 seems unecessary.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the meaning and use of variables. It is pretty much impossible to map from variable names as strings to variables and vice versa, without standing on your head and using things like `eval` or `window[varname]`. Basically, you need to structure your code. If you want to have named values you can access using their name as a string, then use objects and properties.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment defining arg1 and arg2 seems unecessary because wherever you are creating you objects you must already be holding some reference to it.

And when you will pass those to function1 you can easily access the arguments like this

```
function1 = function () {
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<arguments.length;i++){
  console.log(arguments[i]); // do anything with arguments[i] == arg1, arg2, 
  ...
 }
};
```